# Rospy message_filter ApproximateTimeSynchronizer issue

Tags: ros, rospy

I installed `ROS melodic` version in `Ubuntu 18.04`.
I'm running a `rosbag` in the background to mock cameras in messages `rostopics`. 
I set the camera names in `rosparams` and iterated through it to capture each camera topics.
 I'm using `message_filter`  `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer`  to get time synchronized data as mentioned in the official documentation, 
http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

But most of the time the callback function to `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` is not being called/is having delay. The code snippet I'm using is given below:

What am I doing wrong here?

> ```
> def  camera_callback(*args):
>     pass # Other logic comes here
> rospy.init_node('my_listener', anonymous=True) 
> camera_object_data = []
> for camera_name in rospy.get_param('/my/cameras'):
>     camera_object_data.append(message_filters.Subscriber(
>         '/{}/hd/camera_info'.format(camera_name), CameraInfo))
>     camera_object_data.append(message_filters.Subscriber(
>         '/{}/hd/image_color_rect'.format(camera_name), Image))
>     camera_object_data.append(message_filters.Subscriber(
>         '/{}/qhd/image_depth_rect'.format(camera_name), Image))
>     camera_object_data.append(message_filters.Subscriber(
>         '/{}/qhd/points'.format(camera_name), PointCloud2)
>  topic_list = [filter_obj for filter_obj in camera_object_data]
>  ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(topic_list, 10, 1,  allow_headerless=True)
>  ts.registerCallback(camera_callback)
>  rospy.spin()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems correct. There is, however, a trouble with perhaps bad timestamps and ergo this synchronizer as well, see http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime for algorithm assumptions.

My recommendation is to write a corresponding node that publishes empty versions of these four msgs all at the same time. If it's still not working in this perfect scenario, there is an issue with the code above. If it is working just fine, then you need to pay attention to the headers.

Given that you have it as a bag file, you can [step through the msgs on the command line](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play) and observe the timestamps as well. (Can also step [within python](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#Python_API)).

```bash
$ rosbag play --pause recorded1.bag # step through msgs by pressing 's'
```

On time-noisy msgs with small payloads, I've just written a node to listen to all these msgs, and republish them all with the latest time found on any of them (for sync'd logging to csv). Not optimal, but it should reveal where the issue lies.